# What does int* pint; pint = (int*)data; mean?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm reading how pointers work [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) because I'm trying to understand qsort(). But the guide gives this code:

```
// increaser
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void increase (void* data, int psize)
{
  if ( psize == sizeof(char) )
  { char* pchar; pchar=(char*)data; ++(*pchar); }
  else if (psize == sizeof(int) )
  { int* pint; pint=(int*)data; ++(*pint); }
}

int main ()
{
  char a = 'x';
  int b = 1602;
  increase (&a,sizeof(a));
  increase (&b,sizeof(b));
  cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

without explaining what the line

```
pint=(int*)data;
```

and

```
pchar=(char*)data;
```

means. I understand what the rest means, but it doesbt quite make sense to me what (char*)data could mean. Is it pointing to the value of char? But how could that be if char is a variable type?

Comment: `(int*)` is casting `data` to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/

Comment: It's a **C style cast**.

Comment: I would highly recommend learning language fundamentals from a [decent book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), rather than from a random website...

Comment: That's a terrible assumption. Multiple types can be the same size.

Comment: @markovchain Many would recommend that you not learn how anything works at that particular site.  :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line `pint = (int*)data` is doing two things

1. The `(int*)data` is a conversion from `void*` to `int*`
2. The `pint = ...` is an assignment of the value to `pint`

Ultimately what this function is attempting to do is increment the value pointed to by `data` by one value.  It's a bit flawed though as a) the signature accepts any pointer type but the implementation only works with a fixed set of types and b) it incorrectly associates sizes with types.

Given that this is C++, a much better way of writing this would be to use a template.  It accepts all input types which support `++`.

```
template <class T>
void increase(T* pValue) {
  ++(*pValue);
}
```

Ideally though you'd just use a reference

```
template <class T>
void increase(T& value) {
  ++value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(int*)data;
```

and

```
(char*)data;
```

are casts from one pointer type to another, in this case from `void*`  to `int*` and `char*`.
And after that the results are assigned to `pint` and `pchar`

Answer (score 2):

data is passed as a void*

(int*)data is casting it to a int*.

Answer (score 1):

```
pint=(int*)data;
```

and

```
pchar=(char*)data;
```

are casting these variables as pointers, just as you would cast a a `double` to an `int`, or vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

`pchar` is a pointer to a `char` - this is what the declaration

```
char* pchar;
```

means. Thus, after the assignment

```
pchar=(char*)data;
```

the pointer `pchar` is pointing to the start of the block pointed to by `data` - and when you offset `pchar` by a number (say 5 - `*(pchar+5)`), it will point to a memory location that is "five chars" from the location pointed to by `data`. Since a `char` is one byte long, this means you are incrementing the location by 5. Since `pint` had been declared as `int* pint`, the same construction `*(pint+5)` will point to a location that is `5*sizeof(int)` away... so the `+5` means different things depending on how the pointer was declared!

In other words - the declaration tells the compiler how to treat the objects pointed to by the pointer, and what to do when you offset the pointer (increment, decrement, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is not variable as any other. It does not hold regular value. What it does is just remembering some place in memory by holding it's address.

On any place in memory could start any variable of any type. By casting pointer into some other type than it was created for (like `(char*)` for example) you let the program know, that he should work with that place in memory as if it was variable of given type.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer points to a place in memory (in 32bit systems the width of ALL pointers is 32bit and 64bit systems is 64bit). When you write `void* pointer` you are telling the compiler that the data in the memory has no type, and therefore the compiler takes default width for to read the contents(eg. 8bit). Remember that the pointer itself is always 32/64 bit, but the data it points differs.

For example when you say char* pointer, it knows that the data is a character and read 2byte for it (32bit). It is the same for int* and others. Or for long* pointer it reads 4byte.

when you write `pchar = (char*)data` you are telling to the CPU (MMU actually) that the data stored at pchar address is a char and therefore when I said read that, read 2byte for me. When you said (short*) your are telling the MMU to read 1byte for you for that pointer.

if you use void*, the system will use its default size which I think is 1byte.